# How to build .jar file which opens in windows GUI

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4. When I build the project and execute the .jar file in dist folder made by IDE in Windows GUI environment, it shows waiting cursor for a moment and then nothing happens. But when I execute the same .jar file using Command Prompt CLI environment it executes the .jar successfully. The command I used to execute the file was:

java -jar D:\USB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EmbInterface\dist\EmbInterface.jar
Also, I have checked the default file association of .jar files. It's set to C:\java....\javaw.exe.

I tried to run it as administrator but when I right clicked the .jar file there was no such option. Someone told me I needed to build a .jar file for windows GUI but I don't know how to do that.

I am using windows 8.

UPDATE: This is written in the Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.8.0-b132 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.1.jar lib/lucene-core-4.6.
 1.jar lib/lucene-demo-4.6.1.jar lib/lucene-queryparser-4.6.1.jar lib/
 sqljdbc4.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: embinterface.LoginFrame
```

Comment: Do you want to execute the program when you double click on the .jar in Windows? If so, you will need to have the proper manifest file in the jar.

Comment: yes, it contains the manifest file when I extract the jar file. and it also have the main class argument. @anonymous

Comment: Can you post the manifest file for us to have a look?

Comment: Yeah sure! I have edited my question and Manifest file description is under the 'UPDATE' heading. @anonymous

Comment: embinterface is the package name under which all classes exist and LoginFrame has been set to be the main class by me. @anonymous

Comment: You need all the dependency jars inside a `lib` folder. The lib folder should be in the same folder as `EmbInterface.jar`

Comment: Those library jars are already there. @anonymous

Comment: Does the GUI show up when you run the project within NetBeans?

Comment: Yes, the GUI shows up and executes normally using NetBeans and even using command prompt. @OliBlogger